# How to use nested case and group together the result in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How to use nested case and grouped together the result.
Here is my Query:

```
SELECT  COUNT(inc.inc_id) AS event_count, 
 CASE inc_data.event_type
 WHEN 'c' then case inc_data.sub_event_type
               when 's' then 'SR' else 'Project'
               end
 WHEN 'i' then 'incident'
 WHEN 'p' then 'Problem'    
 WHEN 'd' then 'Decision'
 WHEN 't' then 'Task'
 end "event_sub_type"
FROM inc INNER JOIN inc_data ON inc.inc_id = inc_data.inc_id     
GROUP BY inc_data.event_type, inc_data.sub_event_type
```

Returns:

```
+-------------+----------------+
| event_count | event_sub_type |
+-------------+----------------+
|           5 | Project        |
|          10 | Decision       |
|          15 | Incident       |
|          20 | Problem        |
|          25 | Task           |
|          30 | SR             |
+-------------+----------------+
```

Expected output:

```
+-------------+----------------+
| event_count | event_sub_type |
+-------------+----------------+
|           5 | Project        |
|          25 | Others         |
+-------------+----------------+
```

How can I modify the above query to get the expected output?

Comment: You just want to filter this two records?

Comment: Yes , and merged others together

Comment: Well what are you using? MySql or Sql Server? They're not at all the same, and Sql Server might be able to solve this via windowing functions that MySql can't use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this?

```
SELECT  COUNT(inc.inc_id) AS event_count, 
(CASE WHEN (inc_data.event_type = 'c' AND inc_data.sub_event_type <> 's') THEN 'Project' ELSE 'Others' END ) "event_sub_type"
            FROM   inc INNER JOIN
            inc_data ON inc.inc_id = inc_data.inc_id
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN (inc_data.event_type = 'c' AND inc_data.sub_event_type <> 's') THEN 'Project' ELSE 'Others' END )
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT  COUNT(inc.inc_id) AS event_count, 
  CASE inc_data.event_type
  WHEN 'c' then case inc_data.sub_event_type
                when 's' then 'Other' else 'Project'
                end
  ELSE 'Project'
  END "event_sub_type"
FROM inc INNER JOIN inc_data ON inc.inc_id = inc_data.inc_id     
GROUP BY inc_data.event_type, inc_data.sub_event_type
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on your output, I'm assuming that you are using MySQL.

MySQL allows you to group by column numbers, so you can replace your GROUP BY clause with this:

```
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Comment: Allows, yes. Good practice? Not often.